# "to write in full"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that means "to write in full"?
Or perhaps an adverb meaning "written in full"?

Example:

> Grade : 7.08
>
> ____ : SEVEN POINT ZERO EIGHT

Comment: wordly (rare); verbally.

Comment: `In words` is fairly common though not a single word.

Comment: http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_33.htm used your "in full" terminology. I guess "in words" works too.

Answer (score 2):

> **spell out**
>   transitive verb
>   1   :  to make plain • *spelled out* the orders in detail
>   2   :  to write or print in letters and in full • numbers are to be *spelled out*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spell%20out

---

You can also use:

> ***write out***:
>   To write in full or expanded form: *All abbreviations are to be written out.*

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/write+out)

Example of usage:

> When writing a check, you need to write out the amount using words (in
>   addition to the numerals in the dollar box).

https://www.thebalance.com/write-numbers-using-words-4083198

Comment: Yes, I guess your answer is the right one. *Spelled out* is an alternative I had already considered. I guess I was looking for something fancier. Something like an antonym of *abbreviate(d)*... But the fact that I went looking for it doesn't necessarily mean it exists.